# One Way mode on data binding issue-WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, multibinding, staticresource

I have two radio buttons (let's call them a' and b').
I would like that if and only if one of them selected, other compenents will be visible.

Other components contains two labels, two additional radio buttons (let's call them a' and b') and one combobox.

When one of the radio buttons selected, other components are really visible.

However, when I selected one of the other radio buttons (a' or b') so all other components become hiddem beside the two first radio buttons (a and b).

For every component which should be visible while a or b selected I did:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName ="HR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding ElementName ="LR" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
```

Any ideas for my problem please?

Thanks!

Comment: Show the converter and with radio button one is always supposed to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have added all other controls into a container control say Grid. and toggle its visibility(Visible,Hidden) using radio buttons.

   [main grid]

-[radio buttons]
 
-[New Grid]
 
- - [your other controls]


you will toggle visibility of [New Grid]

Comment: But also the two radio buttons exists on the grid.., and a and b radio buttons should be always visible.

Comment: while I define grid and below more grid I got an error:"The property content is set more than one"-any idea please?

Comment: @Programmer your main grid has radio buttons and the "new grid".this "new grid" will enclose your "other controls".it seems you were defining the other grid outside main grid and window can have only 1 child.